# How can I allow mobile data but disable all outgoing texts and all outgoing phone calls?

Tags: sms, calls, mobile-data, android-12, google-pixel-6

I have a Google Pixel 6 on Android 12.

How can I allow mobile data but disable outgoing texts and outgoing phone calls?

Comment: besides uninstalling phone app and messages app I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

I honestly can't say regarding the pixel 6. That's one thing I miss about the old mobiles.  There is a company " ScaleFusion" that offers this. While it looks like it may be intended for mass implementation , they may have it available for individual consumers.

You could always use a hidden vault or dialer in the interim.
Then place this fake dialer on the home screen
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=come.wakeappbase.dialerprank.